# WordPress Error: $(...).carousel is not a function even after JS file enqueued

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

For the life of me, I cannot understand why I keep getting this error. The JS script did enqueue and the console.log test does shows up in the browser as you can see below.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

[image: Screenshot of errors side by side]

Please see JS and Functions.php code below.

**Carousel JS code**: I dropped this in a syntax checker and it said it was fine.

```
var $ = jQuery; //This fixed the WordPress error “Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function” 

$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log( "Testing blog-tab-carousel.js file. It is properly enqueued." );

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#newsCarousel').carousel({
     interval: 4000
    }).on('click', '.list-group li', function() {
     clickEvent = true;
     $('.list-group li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
     if (!clickEvent) {
      var count = $('.list-group').children().length - 1;
      var current = $('.list-group li.active');
      current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
      if (count == id) {
       $('.list-group li').first().addClass('active');
      }
     }
     clickEvent = false;
    });
   })

   $(window).load(function() {
    var boxheight = $('#newsCarousel .carousel-inner').innerHeight();
    var itemlength = $('#newsCarousel .item').length;
    var triggerheight = Math.round(boxheight / itemlength + 1);
    $('#newsCarousel .list-group-item').outerHeight(triggerheight);
   });
```

**Functions.php** relevant snippets

```
function enqueue_blog_custom_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog-tab-carousel', '/wp-content/themes/kiddieacademy/css/blog-tab-carousel.css', false ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_blog_custom_styles' );

function enqueue_blog_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'blog-tab-carousel', '/wp-content/themes/kiddieacademy/js/custom/blog-tab-carousel.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_blog_custom_script' );
```

**Note:** The Original developer deregistered jQuery in the functions.php. I noticed that when I comment it out, the console.log test for the blog carousel does display in the console. If I remove the comment, keeping the  wp_deregister_script('jquery'); then the console.log won't show up.

```
function enqueue_theme_scripts() {
    /* Remove the jquery script
     wp_deregister_script('jquery');  */
    require_js("mousewheel");
    require_js("fancybox");
}
```

Comment: Did you include the plugin file for the carousel after the jQuery file include?

Comment: @Taplar it's wordpress

Comment: I understand that, but his first line is `var $ = jQuery` in the global scope. @KevinB

Comment: No, because they have a jQuery v1.12.4 JS file in their site files. Should I?

Comment: Ok, so their file includes jQuery, jQuery migrate (from your screen capture), and their logic?

Comment: Well, no, you should include it the way scripts are supposed to be included in wordpress. it's not quite the same as just putting a script tag on the page.

Comment: Taplar: Yes, they have both jquery and jquery-migrate.min.js. I'm not the original developer. So I don't know and no one is available to talk. Sorry.

Comment: And thank you Kevin B! I look forward to your help also.

Comment: That's strange then.  The plugin *should* be registering to the jQuery it includes.  And if you are not including your own it shouldn't be destroying the jQuery they include.  If you crack open your developer tools, go to console and type `jQuery.fn.carousel` what does it print out?

Comment: jQuery.fn.carousel
undefined

Comment: In the admin panel, I don't see a plugin for jQuery migrate in the plugins section though. I see Jetpack and other stuff.

Comment: Something else is going on here then that I'm missing.  Since that printed out undefined, that means the carousel plugin is not registered on the version of jQuery that exists in the global namespace.

Comment: How do I register the custom carousel js file with the jQuery version 1.12.4?

Comment: Like this? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raewrites/484cc0bdaac25041e01bdb1a8ce02f59/raw/7e2e2290c5b9681833fd2b089eacdc6af9bfc8a2/enqueue-simple.php

Answer (score 0):

I've often found that what works one one site with redefining $ doesn't work elsewhere. Personally, I use this and it works most times:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $ = jQuery; // probably not needed, but seems to help in a "belt & braces" kinda way!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is SOLVED now. Turns out the original development company did not enqueue the Bootstrap and CSS scripts so the carousel didn't work. I had to download the physical files and place it in the theme folders in their multi-site hierarchy.

Thank you everyone for trying!

**You can close this now.**

Comment: This is because of your min js file is loading after the script that is the only issue.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you understood what I meant. I'm good now.